# Unable to add object to an array in angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to add object into the Fee object array. The structure of fee object is as follows

```
export interface DomicileFee  {
    fieldInfo: FieldInfo;
    value?: number;
}
```

The method that i am trying to add the object is below

```
private filterFees(fees: BackendDto.DomicileFee[]) {
    if (fees !== null) {
      const fee = 'Fee';
      this.totalFees = 0;
      this.captiveAssumptionsFees = fees.filter(a => a.fieldInfo.key.endsWith(fee) === false );

      fees.filter(a => a.fieldInfo.key.endsWith(fee)).forEach(a => { this.totalFees += a.value; });
      //fees.push(this.totalFees);
    }
  }
```

I need to be able to add a new object and assign this.totalFees to it. 
For e.g

```
 fieldInfo : 'genExp' and value : this.totalFees
```

I tried this and it works but it keeps adding when that piece of code is run. I need to add only once

```
fees.push({ fieldInfo: {key: 'generalExpenses' } as FieldInfo, value: this.totalFees });
```

Comment: can you show more code of you `ts` component ?

Comment: I tried this and it works but it keeps adding when that piece of code is run.  Ineed to add only once  fees.push({ fieldInfo: {key: 'generalExpenses' } as FieldInfo, value: this.totalFees });

Answer (score 0):

Since you add the total object with a specific key, you can just check to see if it has already been added. This way you can add the element if it is not present, but you can just replace the data if it is.

```
private filterFees(fees: BackendDto.DomicileFee[]) {
    if (fees !== null) {
      const fee = 'Fee';
      this.totalFees = 0;
      this.captiveAssumptionsFees = fees.filter(a => a.fieldInfo.key.endsWith(fee) === false );

      fees.filter(a => a.fieldInfo.key.endsWith(fee)).forEach(a => { this.totalFees += a.value; });

      const existingData = fees.find(item => item.fieldInfo.key === "generalExpenses");
      if (existingData) {
        existingData.value = this.totalFees;
      } else {
        fees.push({ fieldInfo: {key: 'generalExpenses' } as FieldInfo, value: this.totalFees });
      }
    }
  }
```